# exercise little influenced than are capitalist firms

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In early 1970’s, the soviet union began to give firms and industries some of the flexibility in adjusting prices that a more informal evolution has accorded the capitalist system. Economists in the United States have hailed the change as a return to the free market.But Soviet firms are no more subject to prices established by free market over which they exercise little influenced than are capitalist firms.

I don't understand "exercise little influenced than are capitalist firms".

Comment: Can you share a link or provide a citation that tells where you found this text? That's considered a good practice.

Comment: Thanks:), and here it is:http://www.testpreppractice.net/practice-tests/reading-comprehension/rc1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Influenced* is a typo; it should read *influence*, the noun. There should also be an article before *free market*.

Parse it like this:

> Soviet firms are no more subject to X than capitalist firms [are subject to X].

*X* here is "prices established by a free market over which they exercise little influence".

That is:

1. It is commonly held that capitalist firms do not exercise influence over prices, because these firms are *subject* to prices which are set by a free market.
2. But in fact capitalist firms **do** exercise a great deal of influence over prices; so the common belief is not true of capitalist firms.
3. And it is not any truer of Soviet firms.

ADDED:  It may be, as Victor Barazov suggests, that it is the markets rather than the prices over which little control is (or is not) exercised. The sentence as it stands is ambiguous; and in any case, it doesn't make any difference to the underlying argument.

Answer (score 3):

First, probably a typo: instead of "influenced" ought to be "influence".

Second, that clause is a bit too long, I think.  Remove "over which they exercise little influence" (relates to "prices"), and you get "Soviet firms are no more subject to prices than are capitalist firms".  The stuff between "prices" and "than" is a combination of two adjective clauses.  The former ("established by free market") defines "prices", the latter ("over which they exercise little influence") defined "market".  Whew!...